# Javascript: pass "this" as "dom" object, not "this" as "this" function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is may hard can explain this. Lets see this:

```
<a onclick="jsFunction (1, 'a', function() { callback(this); }"></a>
```

the callback needs to know the `<a>` where this call come from. But this "this" is not that "this" what I want.
There is a little workaround, I know:

```
<a onclick="var _this = this; jsFunction (1, 'a', function() { callback(_this); }"></a>
```

but I feel it unlucky. Is there a better solution?

Comment: There would be plenty of better solutions that don't use inline event handlers. If you're using, or are willing to use, jQuery then you should probably use that to bind your event handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a little less awkward using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) but not much :

```
<a onclick="jsFunction (1, 'a', (function(){callback(this);}).bind(this))"></a>
```

That's one of the many reasons it's generally preferable to not inline the javascript code in the HTML.

I would generally prefer to write this :

```
<a id=someid></a>

<script>
    $('#someid').click(function(){
        var _this=this;
        jsFunction (1, 'a', function() { callback(_this); });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes, keep HTML and JavaScript separated. We're not in 1998 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you mean by "unlucky", but that's a perfectly valid and common way of doing it.

Another way is to use the `bind` method:

```
function() { /* use this as usual here */ }.bind(this);
```

If you want to support ancient browsers, you'll have to use one of them "polyfills" for that (available from your friendly neighborhood Google)

Also, consider not putting code inside your HTML. It gets messy fast.

Comment: because this way the function does a bit more than it is designed for. EDIT: yes, I used this way many times in timer, JSON requests etc. so I thought there might be an easier solution.

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense, unless there's a culture out there that considers potentially messy code "unlucky"

Answer (score 0):

When you get into the world of true OO based languages like Java you will see ways to do this differently with polymorphism etc., but even then in most cases you do exactly what you did, assign "this" before changing to function scope.

"this" is a keyword based on scope I think, so assigning something like objHandel=this or something similar is fine because it makes sense. "this" changes depending on where you are.

Either way I Think your code is still valid and fine... and in a scripting language if you have it working then I think you are pretty lucky thus far :p

~ Dan